# What's the time complexity of Python's collections.Counter.total()?

Tags: python, python-collections

What's the time complexity of Python's collections.Counter.total()? I've read the documentation for the [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html), but there's not mention of its efficiency.  Does anyone know how the method is implemented under the hood and what its time complexity is?

Comment: There are many implementations of Python.

Comment: Almost certainly it is linear, although I suppose the total could be calculated each time the dict is modified and then the method just retrieves this total, but I doubt it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CPython, it looks like it implements [`total()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9f2f7e42269db74a89fc8cd74d82a875787f01d7/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L594) using `sum(self.values())`, so it's `O(number of values in the Counter)`.